# Выходные параметры в потоке c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть метод, который я хочу передать в поток. У него есть выходной параметр
startDriver(out int driver);
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: [Читали?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/creating-threads-and-passing-data-at-start-time)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал делегат в который засунул свой метод

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate () { StartDriver(out int driver); });
```